# Increment TemplateBeginIndex in a DWT

Tags: 2009

I think i'm facing a problem in this block of code:

```
    <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="((TemplateRepeatIndex+1) % 2) == 0" -->
    <div class='moduleDe2'></div>
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

it works perfectly without the "+1". I think `templateRepeatIndex+1`is interpretated as 01 11 21 31 41 etc ...

Sorry if that's a stupid question, i'm sure the solution is easy.
Thank you for your help

Comment: can you try: <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="(((TemplateRepeatIndex)+1) % 2) == 0" -->

Comment: thank you but it does not work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2011, one of the templates is using

```
<span class="number">@@parseInt(${TemplateRepeatIndex})+1@@</span>
```

I believe DWT to JScript based, so you can use stuff like that to enforce type.  I did check the project for Custom Functions, but there isn't one, so I think that should work out of the box, so to speak.

In a conditional, something like

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="(parseInt(TemplateRepeatIndex)+1) % 2 == 0" -->
```

should work (untested).

Comment: thank you for your help. i get the following error :
JScriptException: Expression 'parseInt("0")+1) % 2 == 0' had error 'Expected ';''

Comment: i also tried to use your first solution and i got this : JScriptException: Expression '@@parseInt(${"0"})+1@@ % 2 == 0' had error 'Invalid character'

Comment: Answer for conditional updated - added a missing bracket.  Not sure why the first wouldn't work as copy/pasted.  Perhaps 2009 doesn't like the ${} syntax?